# NextJs caching File content

Tags: reactjs, next.js, caching

I have a project in the NextJs. In the client component, I have an add-button, which I can use to create new server config data (name, url) and save it to the file on the server side (this file content array's server configs). But when I update this file I want to rerender the component on the server side. If I use get server-configs data from the fetch, I can use revalidate for cache, but I don't fetch this data from the server but from the file. So I want to know do you know any method, by which can I revalidate this component and it has to again load the whole file and fetch URLs (here don't have to invalidate every URL, because I only add one server config to the array).